# char * compare with std string wrong result

Tags: c++, linux

case 1:

```
std::string dd = "5A"
char checkSum[9]   
checkSum[0] = '5';  
checkSum[1] = 'A';  
if(strcmp(dd.c_str(),checkSum) == 1){ 
return 1;
} 
else {return 0;}
```

**RESULT: returns 1 //Correct!**

case 2:

```
std::string dd = "0A"
char checkSum[9];  
checkSum[0] = '5';  
checkSum[1] = 'A';  
if(strcmp(dd.c_str(),checkSum) == 1){  
return 1;
} 
else {return 0;}
```

**RESULT: returns 0 //Correct!**

case 3:

```
std::string dd = "5A"    
char checkSum[9]    
checkSum[0] = '0'; 
checkSum[1] = 'A'; 
if(strcmp(dd.c_str(),checkSum) == 1){ 
return 1;
} 
else {return 0;}
```

**RESULT: returns 1 //Not Correct!**

Anyone knows whats wrong? thx!

Comment: Please post real code and take the trouble to format it correctly. Please edit the question.

Answer (score 7):

`strcmp` requires two null-terminated strings, but you are not adding a null-terminator to `checkSum`.

This is why case 1 returns `1` when in fact it should return `0`. Note that your expected values are incorrect. In case 1, once you have added in the null-terminator, the two strings should compare as equal. And so `strcmp` will return `0` and your code should also return `0`.

For case 2, `strcmp("0A", "5A")` returns a negative value since `'0'<'5'` and so your code should return `0`.

For case 3, `strcmp("5A", "0A")` returns a positive value, and it just so happens that the positive value is `1` which you are mistakenly testing for by equality.

In all cases testing for a value of `1` is incorrect since `strcmp` never promises to return `1`. It promises to return either:

- a value of `0` to indicate that the two strings are equal, or,
- a positive value to indicate that `str1` compares greater than `str2`, or,
- a negative value to indicate that `str1` compares less than `str2`.

The only valid comparisons on the return value of `strcmp` are therefore `==0`, `>0` or `<0`.

You need to revisit the documentation for `strcmp` and correct your understanding of how to interpret the return value.

Comment: That's right, but it's not the reason for *case 3* code to behave the way that surprises the OP.

Comment: @Antonio No, I think I've got that now. The expected values in the question are incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

Your checksum contain undefined data you don't add a '\0' termination character in it. It is unexpected behavior if you call the strcmp. You could declare your checksum as:
char checkSum[9] = {0};
but better solution is to avoid unsafe character arrays, use std::string instead.

Answer (score 0):

`strcmp` return value:

> A **zero value** indicates that both strings are **equal**. A value **greater
>   than zero** indicates that the first character that does not match has a
>   **greater value in str1 than in str2**; And a value **less than zero**
>   indicates **the opposite**.

(Extract from http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strcmp/)

Answer (score 0):

Also you should *never* compare the result of `strcmp` with anything else then zero as in

```
strcmp(s1, s2) == 0
strcmp(s1, s2) > 0    
strcmp(s1, s2) < 0
strcmp(s1, s2) != 0
```

as the standard does not guerantee a `1` (or `-1`) in the case of difference.